# DNS servers ignore my client's query

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a problem with a ubuntu-10.4 VM.
When I try to resolve a hostname (using for example nslookup or firefox), my DNS server receive an UDP packet with a DNS query (I saw it with tcpdump), but it drop the request.
I tried with a Windows DNS server and a Red Hat DNS server: they receive the query but give no answer. 
I'm shure that at the end of the installation the name resolution worked !

I have another linux VM: the same query get a response.
Comparing requests with tcpdump and wireshark I found no differences between them.

Comment: Post the IPTables rules

Comment: Feels like a routing issue to me

Comment: Ther isn't any firewall. tcpdump show me that dns server receive a query and doesn't send any response: I run tcpdump on the server and for a 'normal' client I see an UDP packet containing a response. It seems to me a problem with a corrupted request, but wireshark doesn't show errors in the packet containing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Check that the DNS server is configured to listen on that IP network
- Turn on DNS query logging to see if the DNS server is getting the request
- Check the DNS server listening on UDP (OK, this is a long shot)

I agree with James Lawrie that you double check your firewall rules